# image zoom with jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Is there any image zoom plugin complitable with jqgrid?

Does anyone had an experience?

I've tried nivozoom, bezoom, fancyzoom and imagepreview plugins but had no luck...

This my custom formatter:

```
$custom = 'function  ImageFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var BigImage = cellvalue;
    var BigImage = BigImage.replace("_t2.jpg", "_t1.jpg");
      return"<a href=\'../../images/products/thumbs/"+ BigImage +"\' class=\'class_of_the_plugin\' title=\'Some Title\'><img src=\'../../images/products/thumbs/"+ cellvalue +"\' alt=\'" + cellvalue + "\'title=\'" + Buyuk + "\' align=\'center\' /></a>";
  }';
```

The filenames and paths are ok. There is no problem with formatter. But the plugins not working anyway. I've tried also for mouseover plugins:

```
<a onclick="return false;" href="......
```

Any help? Any idea?
Cheers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you overwrite cellvalue, try to cange your code to this:

```
var BigImage = cellvalue.replace("_t2.jpg", "_t1.jpg");
```

It may solve the problem.

Comment: I've no proplem with this. the value replacing succesfully.

Comment: posted another answer, hope it would help. if not, you will need to provide more details for your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Nivozoom, you need to call the plugin after you call your function like this example:

```
var image =  ImageFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
... rest of your code 
... after you updated the new thumbnail
$('.class_of_the_plugin').nivoZoom({
    speed:500,
    zoomHoverOpacity:0.8,
    overlay:false,
    overlayColor:'#333',
    overlayOpacity:0.5,
    captionOpacity:0.8
});
```